# Good way to bundle two different webapps with gulp served by the same Node server, deployed to Heroku?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, npm, gulp

Let's say I have two angular apps using https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate in subdirectories of my root express project. Each one has some common gulp task names then to build themselves. I'd like to serve the apps respectively on their own endpoints off the same host, e.g. `example.com/app1`, `example.com/app2`. What's the best way to kick off the individual gulp builds for each app and serve the static dist/ dirs on their respective endpoints? I don't want to check in the dist dirs to my repo, so I'd like to do the build on Heroku itself at deploy time.

One ugly solution I could do is give each app's gulp tasks unique names, and have a master gulpfile.js at the root call the respective tasks as appropriate, and only do an `npm install` at the root dir, making sure that no `node_modules/` exists in the subdirs. But is there a more elegant way? E.g., maybe in a postinstall script, run `npm install; gulp` for each app, although I don't know if the modules would be cached in that case.

Here's an example layout that would be ideal if I could operate independently in each app dir, and then wire everything up from root/ when it comes time to deploy the server serving it all, but I haven't gotten to work in part because of nested node_modules/.

`root/
├── gulpfile.js
├── node_modules/
├── app1/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── gulpfile.js
├── app2/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── gulpfile.js`

Comment: Could you provide a simple preview of your project folder organization, especially where and if there are more than one `node_modules` folder ?

Comment: i think both gulp files have different paths.. so what you can do is specify path explicitly during running the task... create an alias for both projects and done

Comment: @entre right, each app ought to have its own gulpfile that would be able to build everything into an app/dist/ folder, independent of the other app (let's ignore common module bundling and sharing for now).

Comment: should I put this as answer?

Comment: @entre can you elaborate upon that in your answer? I'm looking to be able to run a single task that drives the build of both apps that is executable on heroku, probably as a postinstall script after all node modules are installed.